# Convert POST to multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a form that creates a $_POST variable like:

```
Array
(
    [submit] => Update the List!
    [12052,s] => 1
    [12052,d] => 0
    [12052,r] => 1
    [11271,s] => 1
    [11271,d] => 0
    [11271,r] => 5
    [16008,s] => 0
    [16008,d] => 0
    [16008,r] => 4
)
```

and I would like to use PHP to convert it to a multidimensional array like:

```
Array
(
    [12052] => Array
        (
            [s] => 1
            [d] => 0
            [r] => 1
        )

    [11271] => Array
        (
            [s] => 1
            [d] => 0
            [r] => 5
        )

    [16008] => Array
        (
            [s] => 0
            [d] => 0
            [r] => 4
        )

)
```

I know that I can make an array like this manually with this code:

```php
$test = array("12052" => array("s"=>"1","d"=>"0","r"=>"1"),"11271" => array("s"=>"1","d"=>"0","r"=>"5"),"16008" => array("s"=>"0","d"=>"0","r"=>"4"));
```

Thanks for helping me figure out how to do this the best way possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($key !== 'submit') {
        $key = strtok($key, ','); // remove everything after ','
        $result[$key][] = $value;
    }    
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/135858)

Comment: Works great! It doesn't set the nested items with the keys of 's','d', and 'r', but it's not a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
$arr = array();
foreach(array_diff_key($_POST, array("submit" => "")) as $key => $val){
    $exp = explode(",", $key, 2);
    $arr[$exp[0]][$exp[1]] = $val;
}
print_r($arr); // Outputs the multidimensional array
```